# Leveraging success on an important project for a promotion or raise

Tags: software-industry, communication, career-development, software, software-development

I work as a Software Developer at a small company. About a month ago I had a conversation with the VP about a issue one of our largest customers is having. Without any orders I took it upon myself to create a mobile app demo to solve this problem for the customer. After great approval I spent about two weeks creating a excellent polished mobile app for the customer with great approval rate with the VP, President, and the customer's higher ups. Now a deal has not yet been made with the customer but I am wondering what the professional opinion would be about talking to the VP about getting something such as a raise, position bump, etc? Any advice on what to do? Anything would be much appreciated.

Edit: Primarily a position change to something with more responsibility.

Comment: I've suggested a change to your question's title to better match what you want to accomplish. Feel free to [change](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/49679/edit) it again if you think it could still be clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this in your back pocket and bring it up during your review.  Asking for money immediately after a single successful project is a bit premature.

Continue showing them that you are a go-getter and your review should be great.

*edit due to comments*

In the comments below you indicated that you aren't interested in a raise AND that your company doesn't do formal reviews.

The best way to proceed is to simply schedule a meeting with your manager.  In the meeting let them know that you want more responsibility and a bump in your position.  Basically - just ask for it.

Comment: Reviews at this company do not happen. I've been here a little over two years and I have yet to have one. Also this is not my first successful project. I have been basically leading another long term project for the past year that has been pretty successful but is hindered by Product Owners laziness/incompetence.

Comment: How do you get pay rises?  Do you?  I would wait a week, and _ask_ for a performance review.  Be proactive on that instead.  Then raise everything you have done since you started.  Be specific and show how you met/exceeded expectations.

Comment: If you don't have formal year end reviews then at year end request a year end meeting to review projects of the year and setting objectives for the next year. In that meeting you can politely ask to discuss pay increases in a non-badgering way.

Comment: I have received my two raises basically asking for them so far. One of the instances I was offered another job for more money and leveraged that. I really enjoy the people I work with so more money doesn't bother me at this point. It would be nice but I am interested in taking on more important roles in the company such as design and leadership since it is lacking in my opinion.

Comment: How long ago was your last raise?  If it's less than six months, you may want to wait that one out then do the performance review.  However, having to threaten to leave to get something to happen is unsustainable.

Comment: Again I am not looking for a raise. Primarily a position change to something with more responsibility. Any opinions about asking for that?

Comment: @user3459799: You might want to update your question to remove the part that says you are looking for a raise.

Comment: @NotMe good idea. Just did.